# Trying to fetch random words from API and displaying them

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, dictionary, fetch

I'm  trying to generate an array of random words fetched from an API and then update for new ones when clicking on a button, right now i can update the array with new words but cant seem to know how to rerender the component after updating the array.
Ive achieved a way but it updates the words, word by word when the loop goes through them and what I want is a way to update all the words at once when the all the words are fetched.

Sorry if ive had a hard time explaning myself, but english is not my native language.

Here is what i have for now with words updatting but not at the same time:

```
const [words, setWords] = useState([]);
  const throwDices = () => {
    words.map((word, index) => {
      fetch("https://palabras-aleatorias-public-api.herokuapp.com/random")
        .then((response) => {
          if (response.ok) {
            return response.json();
          }
          throw Response;
        })
        .then((data) => {
          words[index] = data.body.Word;
          setWords([...words]);
        });
    });
  };
  useEffect(() => {
    throwDices();
  }, []);
```

Comment: If you don't use the return value of `.map()` then `.map()` is the wrong tool

Comment: Consider using an api that returns the amount of words that you are looking for. With your code setup, you aim to make an API request for a single word

Answer (score 0):

This answer is inspired by [this](https://gomakethings.com/waiting-for-multiple-all-api-responses-to-complete-with-the-vanilla-js-promise.all-method/) article

```
const [words, setWords] = React.useState();

const callApiTenTimes = async () => {
  // create an array of promises
  let promises = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    promises.push(fetch("https://palabras-aleatorias-public-api.herokuapp.com/random"));
  }

  // wait for all promises to fulfill
  Promise.all(promises)
    .then((responses) =>
      // Get a JSON object from each of the responses
      Promise.all(responses.map((res) => res.json()))
    )
    .then((data) => {
      // Get all the data and store it in our useState
      const results = data.map(({ body }) => body.Word);
      setWords(results);
    })
    .catch((err) => console.warn(err));

};

// On first render when words === undefined, call API once to fetch first 10 words
useEffect(() => {
  if (!words) {
    callApiTenTimes();
  }
}, [words]);

return (
  <>
    {/* render each word in the word array */}
    {words.map((word) => (
      <p>{word}</p>
    ))}
    {/* get new words after a button click */}
    <button onClick={() => callApiTenTimes()}>Get new words</button>
  </>
)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but the problem i have then is that there is no api in spanish that returns the solicited amount of words, theres only one and it gives one at a time

Comment: I've updated the answer to better match your situation.

Comment: I know it says don't use comments to say thank you buuut, thank you! I've tried to implement promises bymyself becacuse I knew it was the correct way to make it work but wasn't getting it correctly, now I get it more clearly, have a good day!

Comment: You're welcome. I also had fun with this problem. It's quite tricky to use the double `Promise.all` but the article gives good insights. If the answer was helpful, I would appreciate an upvote on my answer or for the answer to be accepted :)

Comment: I did plenty of times in hopes it would add the upvote but i need more reputation for my upvote to work :/

Comment: Thats true! thanks for trying tho and I'm sure you'll get reputation any time soon